# Error on loading after upgrade to 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu, session, .profile

I have recently upgraded my system to 14.04LTS from 12.04LTS.
After the kubuntu display, I received this message

```
Error found when loading /home/username/.profile :\n\nstdin is not a tty\n\n As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix this problem as soon as feasible.
```

After, I clicked the OK button, it disappeared and I could and my screen came up a per the normal fashion. But this message, reappears each time I start my system.

I tried the following command in vain

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

The contents of my .profile file are

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then    
 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then    
    . ~/.bashrc    
 fi    
fi

mesg n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270923&p=13259188#post13259188), the problem is `mesg n`:

> At the end of that file you have:
>
> ```
> mesg n
> ```
>
> But it doesn't works in graphical mode because (taken from man mesg)
>   "mesg assumes that its standard input is connected to your terminal".
>
> Change it to:
>
> ```
> if `tty -s`; then
>    mesg n
> fi
> ```

I'd say that `mesg n` should be in your `.bashrc`, not in `.profile`, which should only assume that it is run in a POSIX shell.

Comment: I've just modified my .profile doc. I'll restart my pc and see, if it works now. where should i place it in .bashrc ?

Comment: @user221478 On second thought, I can't think of a good place to put it. The check given in the forum post should be enough.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.  I had searched the forum, but I was unable to find the solution you mentioned